# Objective c Disable Autolayout Localization Behavior for Arabic

Tags: objective-c, xcode, arabic, right-to-left

I have a code that **does not use autolayout** in its views and it is written in Obj-C.

I want to keep the view as it is (left to right) when is switched to Arabic language.

I know that there is a way of preventing this to happen if I was using autolayout constraints ([Respect or not the Language Direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19916926/disable-autolayout-localization-behavior-rtl-right-to-left-behavior)), but what if I am not using autolayout constraints and want to disable the feature that turns my app RTL direction for Arabic version?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force your UIView's direction by using [UISemanticContentAttribute](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UISemanticContentAttribute)

i.e, to force Right to left direction, apply

```
[myView setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceRightToLeft];
```

On your view.

Comment: Hi Shai, thanks for the help, based on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31697426/ios-9-disable-support-for-right-to-left-language they pointed out that this method is not a safe way and may lead to other issues, how true is that?

Comment: Thank you so much brother.It saved me from 3 days trying.I have been achieving for 3 days.Now only I get it by using your answer.So I up voted it.