# Button unclickable on changing Localization

Tags: ios, objective-c, button, localization, uibutton

My code is localized for two languages i.e. English and Arabic. I have placed a button on the top left of screen for side menu. When running the app in English localization, everything works perfectly, but when changing the device language to Arabic, the side menu button becomes unclickable. In Arabic localization, the default screen from left to right becomes right to left i.e. button on the top left in English localization gets placed in top right instead, in Arabic. Apart from that, I'm able to open the side menu from swipe gesture in both localizations.

Comment: I've used autoLayout for the design. On changing the language to Arabic, iPhone automatically transforms into English layout's mirage(mirror reflection).

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the **right to left** behaviour in arabic by [Disable Autolayout Localization Behavior (RTL - Right To Left Behavior )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19916926/disable-autolayout-localization-behavior-rtl-right-to-left-behavior)

OR

just remove arabic from localization and add new option in your app for arabic language and do all what you need in arabic by manually.

Comment: thnx for the comment, but I asked for the reason for button getting unclickable in Arabic while working fine for English layout.

Comment: May be some constraint issue... View Debugging help you https://koenig-media.raywenderlich.com/uploads/2015/03/Screenshot-1.png https://www.raywenderlich.com/98356/view-debugging-in-xcode-6